# Definition of product implies the existence of continuous function?

Tags: general-topology, definition, proof-explanation, products, path-connected

What is the definition of product that it's being   considered here to have the existence of a unique continuous function ?

> Let $X_i$ be path connected topological spaces.
>
> Then $\prod_i X_i$ is path connected.

**Proof.**

Assume $X=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ with $X_i$ path-connected.
Let $x=(x_i)_{i\in I}$, $y=(y_i)_{i\in I}$ be two points in $X$.
By assumption, thee exist continuous paths $\gamma_i\colon[0,1]\to X_i$ with $\gamma_i(0)=x_i$ and $\gamma_i(1)=y_i$.

**By definition of product**, there exists a unique continuous $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to X$ such that $\pi_i\circ\gamma=\gamma_i$ for all $i\in I$ where $\pi_i$ is the projection $X\to X_i$. That makes $\gamma$ a path from $x$ to $y$.

This proof is from here
[Product of path connected spaces is path connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454627/product-of-path-connected-spaces-is-path-connected) .

Comment: This is the [universal property of the product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property#Products). It defines the product of topological spaces up to unique isomorphism and you should check that the usual definition of the product topology does satisfy the universal property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product of topological spaces has as underlying set the Cartesian product: an element of $\prod_iX_i$ is a tuple $(x_i)_{i \in I}$. In other words, an element of $\prod_i X_i$ has a coordinate $x_i$ in each one of the $X_i$. The product topology is the one generated by sets of the form

$$\prod_{i} U_i,$$

where all the $U_i \subseteq X_i$ are open and $U_i = X_i$ for all but finitely many $i$'s. Hence, sets like the above form a basis for the product topology on $\prod_i X_i$.

Now, why does this definition has anything to do with continuity? For this, notice that for each $k \in I$ we have a very natural map, called the $k-$th projection:

$$ \pi_k \colon \prod_i X_i \to X_k, (x_i) \mapsto x_k.$$

Now you should check the following:

- For all $k \in I$, $\pi_k$ is continuous
- A map $\phi \colon Z \to \prod_i X_i$ is continuous if and only if all the compositions $\pi_k \circ \phi \colon Z \to X_k$ are continuous.

When you think your background is solid enough (and when you have checked the above by yourself), I encourage you to have a look at [this](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/topologies.pdf) very useful notes of professor Emily Riehl. They are not particularly difficult, but they are a bit abstract, so that it is probably better to have already some confidence with the concepts treated in order to gain the most out of it.

Comment: I don't particularly fancy your notation of the topological basis, since you've started your argument with set theory (which in turn I like, because that is usually the approach for beginners). I'd rather write something like '*$\Pi_{i \in I} U_i\,,\,U_i = X_i$ for almost all $i \in I$*', because this is the actual basis in terms of set-equality (what you gave is set equality up to set isomorphism). I know I'm splitting hairs, but for some people, avoiding that tad confusion less can make a difference, especially when everything's new :) Other than that +1, also for the Riehl reference.

Comment: @polynomial_donut I understand your point. I have thought about the right way to put it and in the end I have chosen this, but I guess you're right that there's a better solution. I'll edit it

Comment: Has the initial topology relation with the second bullet statement ?

Comment: @bella Yes, it does! The product topology is exactly the initial topology for the projections $\pi_k$

Comment: oh I didn't  know that, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Topological space $X$ equipped with continuous maps $\pi_i:X\to X_i$ for every $i\in I$ serves as product for the family $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ of topological spaces iff for every topological space $Y$ and every family of continuous functions $(g_i:Y\to Y_i)_{i\in I}$ there is a unique continuous function $g:Y\to X$ such that $g_i=\pi_i\circ g$ for every $i\in I$.