# Complement of a complex line in $\Bbb C^2$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

Is the set $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus\{z_1=0\}$ connected?

My try:

Let points $p=(p_1,p_2)$ i $q=(q_1,q_2)$ such that $p_1=a_1+ib_1=r_1e^{i \phi_1}$ and $q_1=c_1+id_1=r_2e^{i \phi_2}$, $r_i>0$. Then
$((tr_1+(1-t)r_2)e^{i(t \phi_1+(1-t) \phi_2},tp_2+(1-t)q_2)$ is path between $p$ i $q$ and doesn't intersect $z_1=0$ because $r_1,r_2>0$ and $t$ or $(1-t)>0$.

Does this make sense?

Can this be generalized for more lines or higher dimensions of complex space?

Comment: your proof is fine. For a generalization, see this duplicate: [Product of path connected spaces is path connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454627/product-of-path-connected-spaces-is-path-connected) $\Bbb C^2\setminus\{z_1=0\}=\Bbb C\times(\Bbb C\setminus\{0\})$ and $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is homeomorphic, via polar coordinates, to $(0,+\infty)\times S^1$).

Comment: What about more lines? For finite set of lines I suppose it is ok, but can't tell why. For infinite maybe not?

Comment: Consider a complex line between these two points. It meets ${z_1=0}$ in at most one point. You can safely connect these two pint by a path in the complex line (a plane) avoiding this point. This argument  works for a finte set of lines, or any algebraic set $(P(z,w)=0$, because a finite set do not disconnect a 2-plane (complex line)..