# Do any two connected spaces have a continuous surjection between them?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

It is known that if $X$ is a connected topological space and there exists a continuous surjection $f:X\to Y$, then so is $Y$.

I wonder if there exist connected topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that there is no continuous surjection between them? I first thought of $S^1$ and Warsaw circle, but it seems that it is not hard to construct a contiuous surjection from Warsaw circle to $S^1$ by cutting the Warsaw circle into infinitely many intervals and mapping each of them to $S^1$.

Remark: WLOG we take $X$ and $Y$ such that $card(X)\geq card(Y)$.

Comment: Hint: if $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $Y$ has to be compact for $f$ to exist.

Comment: What if $X$ is a one point space, and $Y$ is a larger connected set?

Comment: @Mark I can construct a continuous surjection from $Y$ to $X$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is perhaps the simplest example (or at least, the smallest possible example!).  Let $X=Y=\{a,b,c\}$ with the following topologies.  The open sets in $X$ are $\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\}$.  The open sets in $Y$ are the closed sets of $X$: $\{a,b,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,c\},\{c\},\emptyset$.  Since $X$ and $Y$ have the same finite cardinality and the same number of open sets, any continuous surjection between them must be a homeomorphism.  However, they are not homeomorphic since $X$ has two open singletons and $Y$ has only one.

Comment: Elegant example! May I know the reference or is it originaly yours?

Comment: I came up with it. It's easy to come up with examples like this if you know some general theory of finite topological spaces (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space#Properties) for some relevant ideas).

Answer (score 7):

Let $X$ be a path connected space and $Y$ be a connected space which is not path connected, with $|X|>|Y|$. (for example you can take $Y$ to be the topologists's sine curve and $X=\Bbb R^\kappa$ for big enough $\kappa$) Then there is no continuous surjection $Y\to X$, because there are no surjections $Y\to X$ at all, while there is no continuous surjection $X\to Y$ because the continuous image of a path connected space is path connected.

There is a positive result along the lines of your question if you work with nice spaces: suppose $X$ and $Y$ are compact connected metrizable locally connected spaces (also known as Peano continua) which are not singletons. Then there is a continuous surjection $X\to Y$ (and a continuous surjection $Y\to X$).

Comment: What's the nature of $\kappa$ on this case? I suppose $\kappa$ must not be a positive integer. I am not familiar with these spaces, could you provide us with some references?

Comment: @Emo $\kappa$ is some arbitrary infinite cardinal which is big enough so that $|\Bbb R^\kappa|>|\Bbb R|$ (since the latter is the cardinality of the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) ). $\Bbb R^\kappa$ is path connected (in the product topology) since [it is a product of path connected spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454627/product-of-path-connected-spaces-is-path-connected).

Comment: But note that the specific spaces don't matter, all you need for the argument to work is $Y$ which is connected but not path connected and $X$ which is path connected with $|X|>|Y|$, you can use your favourite spaces that have those properties instead of those from my answer